# Releasing view from stack, tab bar with nav controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

So I am working on a vital update to an app I have on the appstore.  I have an app with a tab bar and a nav controller.  When the user selects an item from the list it sends the link it is getting from the xml file sent from my server to a detail view controller that is only a web view.  The problem I'm having is when the user goes back to the tableview which is the root view for that tab the detail view isn't being released.  When you select the other options in the app, the detail view doesn't change.  It's not that my data isn't being released from the uishared application data but its the view isn't releasing.  I know that there are many similar items like this on here and i've tried all of them.  I will give you some of my code and greatly appreciate other tips and tricks.  Im 15 and just getting into development so any info helps.  Heres the code i think is necessary for anyone to help.

TableViewController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
    NSString * storyLink = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"link"];

    // clean up the link - get rid of spaces, returns, and tabs...
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@""];

    videoDetailViewController.title = @"Videos";

    ExampleAppDataObject* theDataObject = [self theAppDataObject];
    theDataObject.videoData = storyLink;

    if (self.videoDetailViewController == nil)
    {
        VideoDetailViewController *aBookDetail = [[[VideoDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VideosDetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
        self.videoDetailViewController = aBookDetail;
        [aBookDetail release];
        aBookDetail = nil;
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:videoDetailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

DetailViewController:

```
#import "VideoDetailViewController.h"
#import "RSSEntry.h"
#import "ExampleAppDataObject.h"
#import "AppDelegateProtocol.h"
    
@implementation VideoDetailViewController

@synthesize activityIndicator;
@synthesize webView;
@synthesize pasteboard;

- (ExampleAppDataObject*) theAppDataObject;
{
    id<AppDelegateProtocol> theDelegate = (id<AppDelegateProtocol>) [UIApplication    sharedApplication].delegate;
    ExampleAppDataObject* theDataObject;
    theDataObject = (ExampleAppDataObject*) theDelegate.theAppDataObject;
    return theDataObject;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    ExampleAppDataObject* theDataObject = [self theAppDataObject];
    NSString *urladdress = theDataObject.videoData;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urladdress];
    NSURLRequest *requestobj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    
    [webView loadRequest:requestobj];
    pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [webView release];
    webView = nil;
    
    [activityIndicator release];

    [pasteboard release];
    
    [VideoDetailViewController release];
    [urlData release];
    urlData = nil;
    
    [super dealloc];
}
        
@end
```

Comment: When you say "not releasing" how do you know that, what are you using to monitor the objects? Also, what appears to the user?

Comment: Well there is a video in this case and when I go back to the nav part of the stack and select any other tableviewcell and go back to the detailview it is still the same video paused at the same spot.

Comment: Ah. MediaPlayer. You may want to do something on your "back" functionality to pause/release the mediaplayer object. Approach it on the object that's still running, essentially, not the container that's containing it.

Comment: its a video in a webview... not native media player

Comment: You may want to ask a new question on here, and tag it with webview, not w/ the controller stuff. You'd get more specific answers (and expertise). Why webview & not MP?

Comment: because its going to display a webpage with comments and details about the video from users that comment on the video..the only reason i only have it playing a video is because it was quicker for development reasons.

Comment: Well this may be a showstopper because you can't tell an embedded html object in a webview to "stop playing" once it's loaded, to my knowledge. and if they press the back button, you'd ideally need to send some kind of instruction to the embedded code that you want it to stop.

Comment: I dont care as much about the media as to reload the view when the user selects a different tableviewcell.  Each cell contains a different url so... Download my app WCH Children its free and on the appstore and select the videos tab and youll see my problem and more what Im talking about

Comment: or i can email you the xcode project

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12362/discussion-between-anna-billstrom-and-evan-stoddard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't release the webview in the detailViewController page, instead, put
`[webView loadRequest:requestobj];` in in viewDidAppear(), not viewDidLoad

Also:
One way to make the transition smoother, change:

```
if (self.videoDetailViewController == nil) {
    VideoDetailViewController *aBookDetail = [[[VideoDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VideosDetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
    self.videoDetailViewController = aBookDetail;
    [aBookDetail release];
    aBookDetail = nil;

}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:videoDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

Should be:

```
VideoDetailViewController *aBookDetail = [[VideoDetailViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"VideosDetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] ;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:videoDetailViewController animated:YES];
[aBookDetail release];
```

Comment: I've written up a fuller example here: http://www.banane.com/2010/03/11/iphone-dev-editing-tableview-with-a-detailview-core-data/

Comment: Ok i tried that but now when i select the other option it doesnt seem to be rebuilding the view and all i see is a balnk white view in the webview

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Anna Billstrom, I realized that I also should be using `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`.  This is because I am passing data to the controller through an external data class when an item is selected from the table view.  Therefore, the detail view controller is loading before there is data to load from the external data class.  viewDidAppear solves this problem by getting data once the view loads after the cell is selected and there is data in the external class.